# Having problems with python code that is meant to count every time 100 appears

Tags: python, counting

I'm tying to create a program that will count every time someone inputs the number '100' and the program will end when '0' is inputted, but the code keeps counting '0' too.

```py
getnumber = int(input())
result1 = 1
while True:
    getnumber = int(input())
    if getnumber == 100:
        result1 = result1+1

    if getnumber == 0:
        print(result1)
```

What has gone wrong here?

Comment: The `while True` will simply go for another cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while True` will instruct to keep repeating the body of that loop. You thus should add a condition for it. As long as `getnumber` is not `0`, you want it to keep iterating, so `while getnumber` should work.

Another mistake is that you do not take the first number you query into account, and that you start `result1` with `1` (instead of `0`).

We can simplify the above to:

```
getnumber = True
result1 = 0
while getnumber:
    result1 += getnumber == 100
    getnumber = int(input())
print(result1)
```

Since a `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `False` and `True` are `0` and `1` respectively, we thus can add `getnumber == 100` to the number.

We use `getnumber` as a condition to check if we go for another loop. As long as `getnumber` is not `0`, we perform another loop. We initialize `getnumber` to `True` since that is not `100` (and it thus will not be counted), and furthermore it will make a loop.